# Unable to see and retrieve values from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I developed this android app by watching a tutorial video, in which they shared a link to download their code. This application saves the values of a form on click of a button. On clicking, it displays the message that values are inserted, but I am unable to see any values in sqlite and unable to retrieve any values as well.

Below is the complete code of the app :-

> add.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint_title" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDuedate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="hint_duedate"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCourse"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="hint_course" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editNotes"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="notes"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" android:lines="6"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addAssignment"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:onClick="addAssignment"
            android:text="add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/viewBtn"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="view" android:onClick="viewAssignments"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> assignment_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="@+id/rowDate"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="331dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.44"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="add" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> addassignment.java:

```
public class addassignment extends Activity {

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add);

    }
    public void addAssignment(View v)
    {
        Log.d("test", "adding");
        //get data from form
        EditText nameTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
        EditText dateTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDuedate);
        EditText courseTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCourse);
        EditText notesTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNotes);

           db.open();        
           long id = db.insertRecord(nameTxt.getText().toString(), dateTxt.getText().toString(), courseTxt.getText().toString(), notesTxt.getText().toString());        
           db.close();

        nameTxt.setText("");
        dateTxt.setText("");
        courseTxt.setText("");
        notesTxt.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(addassignment.this,"Assignment Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

    }

    public void viewAssignments(View v)
    {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AssignmentTracker.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

> AssignmentTracker.java:

```
public class AssignmentTracker extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    //DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(AssignmentTracker.this, addassignment.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        try {           
            String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/AssignmentDB";
            File f = new File(destPath);            
            if (!f.exists()) {          
                CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"), 
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 


        //---add an assignment---
        /*
        db.open();        
        long id = db.insertRecord("Hello World", "2/18/2012", "DPR 224", "First Android Project");        
        id = db.insertRecord("Workbook Exercises", "3/1/2012", "MAT 100", "Do odd numbers");
        db.close();
        */

        //---get all Records---
        /*
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllRecords();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {          
                DisplayRecord(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        */

        /*
        //---get a Record---
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getRecord(2);
        if (c.moveToFirst())        
            DisplayRecord(c);
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Assignments found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.close();
        */


        //---update Record---
        /*
        db.open();
        if (db.updateRecord(1, "Hello Android", "2/19/2012", "DPR 224", "First Android Project"))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Update successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Update failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
        db.close();
        */

        /*
        //---delete a Record---
        db.open();
        if (db.deleteRecord(1))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Delete successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Delete failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
        db.close();
        */
    }

    private class DBAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        //private ArrayList<>

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            return null;
        }

    }

    public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) 
    throws IOException {
        //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public void DisplayRecord(Cursor c)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, 
                "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                "Title: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                "Due Date:  " + c.getString(2),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
    } 

    public void addAssignment(View view)
    {

        Intent i = new Intent("com.pinchtapzoom.addassignment");
        startActivity(i);
        Log.d("TAG", "Clicked");
    }

}
```

> DBAdapter.java:

```
public class DBAdapter {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_DUEDATE = "duedate";
    public static final String KEY_COURSE = "course";
    public static final String KEY_NOTES = "notes";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AssignmentsDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "assignments";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table if not exists assignments (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "title VARCHAR not null, duedate date, course VARCHAR, notes VARCHAR );";

    private final Context context;    

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);    
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a record into the database---
    public long insertRecord(String title, String duedate, String course, String notes) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
        initialValues.put(KEY_COURSE, course);
        initialValues.put(KEY_NOTES, notes);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular record---
    public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the records---
    public Cursor getAllRecords() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_DUEDATE, KEY_COURSE, KEY_NOTES}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    //---retrieves a particular record---
    public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_TITLE, KEY_DUEDATE, KEY_COURSE, KEY_NOTES}, 
                KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a record---
    public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String title, String duedate, String course, String notes) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
        args.put(KEY_COURSE, course);
        args.put(KEY_NOTES, notes);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

> My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pallavi.sqlitecon"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application

        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AssignmentTracker"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".addassignment"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i am not getting any errors but function is not performed...i am new to android....suggest me any program to connect sqlite3 and android and retrieve values from it..even i have installed sqlite in my system..

Comment: First of all I think that you should have apostrophes over the word for the where clause for example over the rowId: KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId should be KEY_ROWID + "='" + rowId + "'" . Secondly did you try to debug your code? For example the `getRecord()` method. If you debug the code, you could see what exactly is happening

Comment: your tutorial is bad. use this one >> http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `sqlite` database browser to check that you table contains values or not 
http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: using that browser i have created database but again if i open it,saying that "an error occurred:  File is not a SQLite 3 database"

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.questoid/com.questoid.sqlitebrowser_1.2.0.jar.zip

Answer (score 0):

Use add below function in your DatabaseHelper class and call it after insert or where ever you want to see database `public static void DbBackup() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),DATABASE_NAME);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            try {
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`

`}`

DB_PATH="/data/data/<your package name>/databases/" is path to your database file 
When you cal this function it will copy database file from databases to SdCard now transfer this database file to your computer and open it using any SQLite browser to see content of your database.

Comment: JaiSoni can you change my program and help me to sought out

Comment: @anuroyal have you successfuly copy database file from data/data to your computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can access this folder using the DDMS for your Emulator.

You can view Table structure and Data in Eclipse. Here are the steps

1.Install SqliteManagerPlugin for Eclipse.

2.Download the *.jar file from here

3.Put the *.jar file into the folder eclipse/dropins/

4.Restart eclipse

5.In the top right of eclipse, click the DDMS icon

6.Select the proper emulator in the left panel

7.In the File Explorer tab on the main panel, go to /data/data/[app package]/databases

8.Under the the DDMS icon, there should be a new blue icon of a Database light up when you select your database. 
Click it and you will see a Questoid Sqlite Manager tab open up to view your data.

Download this Questoid SqLiteBrowser: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.questoid/com.questoid.sqlitebrowser_1.2.0.jar.zip

Unzip and put it into eclipse/dropins

For more information  [see here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)

After that you can see the data in the database wheather it is inserted or not ?

Comment: i am using android studioo plss suggest steps for that -Sabya

Answer (score 0):

To know about sqlite database created by you in android studio, you need to follow simple steps:

1.Run your application

2.Go to Tools--->Android---->Device Monitor

3.Find your application name in left panel

4.Then click on File Explorer tab

5.Select data folder

6.Select data folder again and find your app or module name

7.Click on your  database name

8.On right-top window you have an option to pull file from device.

9.Click it and save it on your PC

For more information follow this link. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/know-where-database-is-stored-in-android-studio/

To view your data present in db file you need to download sqlite browser or add plugin of the same in any browser so you need to open file in browser and view your data.

Download browser from http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: Sabya can you improve the program to show the stored data...when view button is clicked